# Pegando erros de validação do HTML 5

Tags: javascript, html5

É possível pegar o evento de um erro de validação do `html5` no javascript?. Por exemplo, o usuário não digitou um campo, onde o mesmo está marcado como `required`, quando ele tentar enviar o formulário será gerado um popup de erro do próprio `html5`, é possível disparar uma função javascript quando isso ocorrer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma opção é utilizar o atributo `oninvalid`:

```
<input type="text" oninvalid="handle();" required>
```

No seu JavaScript defina a função

```
function handle() {
    // ...
}
```

[Veja a documentação](https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/ev_oninvalid.asp) do `oninvalid` no w3schools.

Pode utilizar de forma diferente. Veja:

```
element.addEventListener("invalid", function() { ... });
```